# What type is [boolean]?

Tags: typescript

Please, look at the following code snippet:

```
var a: boolean[] = [];
var b: [boolean];
a = [true, false, true];
b = [true, false];
b.push(true);
b = []; //compile error: 
b = a; // compile error
```

First compile error:

> Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type '[boolean]'. Property '0'
>   is missing in type 'undefined[]'

Second compile error:

> Type 'boolean[]' is not assignable to type '[boolean]'. Property '0'
>   is missing in type 'boolean[]'

It seems that `[boolean]` type is something like `array of boolean`. but it is not exactly the same.

What is the difference between `[boolean]` and `boolean[]` types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`boolean[]` is an [array type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#384-array-type-literals). `[boolean]` is a [tuple type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#385-tuple-type-literals). Here's the first part of [what the spec says](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.3.3) about tuple types:

> Tuple types represent JavaScript arrays with individually tracked element types. Tuple types are written using tuple type literals (section 3.8.5). A tuple type combines a set of numerically named properties with the members of an array type. Specifically, a tuple type
>
> ```
> [ T0, T1, ..., Tn ]
> ```
>
> combines the set of properties
>
> ```
> {  
>     0: T0;  
>     1: T1;  
>     ...  
>     n: Tn;  
> }
> ```
>
> with the members of an array type whose element type is the union type (section [3.4](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.4)) of the tuple element types.

Since with `[boolean]` the type of the 0th element must be `boolean`, `b = []` fails (the type of the 0th element is `undefined`), and `b = a` fails (`b` and `a` are different types, and while `a`'s type guarantees that the 0th element, if any, will contain a boolean, it doesn't guarantee that there will be one).